# PHP preg_replace numbers following immediately after a match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

here is the sample string I will be working with:

`john:4 40 4 guy:42 402 42 jack:6 666 8`

I am trying to match the word `guy`, and replace the following three numbers with other data. Here is a variation of what I have been trying

```
$userString = "john:4 40 4 guy:42 402 42 jack:6 666 8";
$expression = "/guy.*?(\d+)/";
preg_replace($expression, 666666666, $userString);
echo $userString;
```

This doesn't work, and I am a bit lost.

Comment: [`=preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) returns its result, it does not get your string variable by reference to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$userString = "john:4 40 4 guy:42 402 42 jack:6 666 8";
$userString = preg_replace('~guy:[^a-z]~i',666666666.' ', $userString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty certain none of the answers so far give the desired output, so here's my interpretation:

You want to replace all three numbers `42 402 42` after `guy:` with your `666666666`.

```
$userString = 'john:4 40 4 guy:42 402 42 jack:6 666 8';
$userString = preg_replace('/(guy:)\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+/', '${1}666666666', $userString);
echo $userString;
```

**Outputs:**

```
john:4 40 4 guy:666666666 jack:6 666 8
```

Comment: or since you always have whitespace after the 3rd number just `/(guy:)(\d+\s+){3}/`

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace()` returns a string so all you'd have to do is assign it to a var:

```
$userString = "john:4 40 4 guy:42 402 42 jack:6 666 8";
$expression = "/guy.*?(\d+)/";
$userString = preg_replace($expression, 666666666, $userString);
echo $userString;
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, it’s best to just do a combo, `preg_match` & `preg_replace` scheme. Yes, it’s juggling but it works & is clear to understand. Here is your code reworked to use this logic:

```
// Your original user string.
$userString = "john:4 40 4 guy:42 402 42 jack:6 666 8";

// This basically grabs `guy:42 402`
$expression = "/guy:.*?\d{2}\s+(\d{3})/";

// This runs the regex.
preg_match($expression, $userString, $matches1);

// This takes `guy:42 402` and replaces the last 3 digits with `666666666`
$replacement = preg_replace("/\d{3}$/", 666666666, $matches1[0]);

// Then this matches the first `guy:42 402` & replaces it with `guy:42 666666666 `
$final = preg_replace("/".$matches1[0]."/", $replacement, $userString);

// Echo the `$final` string for review.
echo $final;
```